# adding row-data of 12 tables while maintaining the filter

Tags: r, merge

I want to create a large table that will consist of 12 tables with same column names of 12 variables. But I only need 8 of the columns.

I've tried selecting the 8 variables from the first table.

```
trip_17_filt <- trip_17_q1[, c('trip_id', 'start_time', 'tripduration', 'from_station_id', 'to_station_id', 'usertype', 'gender', 'birthyear')]
```

Now, I want to add the rest of the 11 tables together while keeping the same variables. What should I do next?

I know that this can be easily done in excel by copy pasting and creating a pivot table, but there's more than a million rows in each of the tables. Therefore, I want to do this in R. This may be a duplicate question, but I still could not understand from other examples.

Comment: Copy and paste your code, editing the table name for the other 11 tables.  Or, put all 12 tables in a `list` and then use `lapply` to drop the unnecessary columns.  Or, `row_bind` the 12 tables into a single, common, table (with an index column to identify the original table, if necessary) and then drop the unwanted columns from the combined table.  You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Comment: All right, let me try that.

Comment: Thanks, @Limey. I tried what you said and it worked. I wrote the same line 12 times and did this: ```trip_filt <- do.call("rbind", list(trip_17_q1_filt, trip_17_q2_filt, trip_17_q3_filt, trip_17_q4_filt, trip_18_q1_filt, trip_18_q2_filt, trip_18_q3_filt, trip_18_q4_filt, trip_19_q1_filt, trip_19_q2_filt, trip_19_q3_filt, trip_19_q4_filt))```